# How can I change sub link color on main menu?

Tags: css, wordpress

I set special CSS for each button on main menu. I want to change sub links in my third button. Theme default set `#ccc` color for every sub links.

```
#main-nav ul ul a,
#main-nav .mega-menu-block a {
    border: 0 none;
    background: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
    line-height: 1.5em !important;
    padding: 7px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 210;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

I change color to transparent first.

```
color: transparent !important;
```

Then I edit my third button class like this:

```
.ucuncu-nav ul ul a,
.ucuncu-nav.mega-menu-block a {
    color: #669900;
}
```

But it's not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ucuncu-nav.mega-menu.mega-recent-featured .mega-menu-block .mega-recent-post a {
    color: blue !important;

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a list to display this list. Try with nth-child property like this:

```
#main-nav ul ul a,
#main-nav .mega-menu-block li:nth-child(3) a div a {
  color:orange !important;
}
```

Hope it helps but the problem is not so clear, because when I see your website the submenu is made by divs and I don´t know if you will place a link there.

Comment: My link is transparent now.So may you not see.under the picture

Comment: Put an !important to it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the full structure HTML of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Its not changing because you have important statement on:

```
#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a, #main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a:hover {
background-color: transparent !important;
color: #fff !important;
```

}

Remove it and you should be fine

Comment: This code block the blue box over the menu buttons.İf I remove that blue box will appear again.Also I tried and not work.